# Delete multiple rows from Grid

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

How do I delete multiple rows from XtraGrid ? I am using DevEx version 10.2. Any tutorials available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected rows using the [GetSelectedRows](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetSelectedRowstopic) method (nicely named right?).
Then you can just use a loop to go through the rows and delete the ones selected.

Also, I found this "tutorial" which might be what you are looking for: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A234.aspx

It talks about the [ColumnView.DeleteSelectedRows](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_DeleteSelectedRowstopic) method, though it's only available in newer versions of XtraGrid.

Comment: select multiple rows from a grid. And delete them on single click. Good to know the theoretical aspect, but would be great if I can see a working code which allows deleting multiple rows from grid at a time. I am able to delete single row by getting focused row handle.

Comment: @buffer check my updated comment. Basically, it's getting an array of focused row handles.

Comment: GetSelectedRows has made it clear. Will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: @buffer Do you have to program it explicitly? I found a method ColumnView.DeleteSelectedRows but it only exists for more recent versions of the XtraGrid. Here is the documentation http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_DeleteSelectedRowstopic

Answer (score 0):

you can't delete more than one row at time but we can Trick on the c#.
actually when you delete one row from the gridview by using this statement  `GridData.Rows.RemoveAt(RowIndex);`
the rows count is decremented by one and the row index will change so you must be careful about that.
here you are, first you can create an integer variable which equal zero and when you remove one row increment it by one.
second, put the index of the rows you want to delete in an array and then use for loop to delete the rows but again take care when you send your parameter.

```
int deletedValue = 0 ;
```

`for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++)`

```
{
if (Array.binarySearch(myArray,j)){
  GridData.Rows.RemoveAt(j-deletedValue); deletedValue++;`
}
else {//The non deleted rows}}
}
```